# Hibernate HQL query results problem

Tags: hibernate

In the web application I'm developing I use this query "from Messages".Although there are 13 records in messages table at my database,when I print the results I get this:
1) id:0 mesname:bla message:bla,bla
2) id:0 mesname:bla1 message:bla1,bla1.
In other words although all the fields of Messages Pojo are set correctly the id field is always 0 as if it is never set. What am I doing wrong?